# could not print the report in reportViewer in >net

Tags: c#, reportviewer

how to print the report in report virewer in Asp.Net2010 (C#).My printing button is visible in IE but it doesn't shown in FireFox

Answer (score 0):

As of 2007, printing was [unavailable in non-IE browsers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9f2b692-929e-4279-97f5-2ceaa55ef17e/print-search-button-not-visible-in-reportviewer-control-in-firefox?forum=sqlreportingservices):

A [much more recent post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150702203646/http://www.visualwebgui.com:80/Developers/Forums/tabid/364/forumid/56/postid/47090/scope/posts/Default.aspx) from 2011 suggests that this is still the case.

[This](https://cafalse.blogspot.com/2011/04/reportviewer-print-button-for-firefox.html) may provide a workaround.